# What is the difference between passport-google-oauth and passport-google-token?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am trying to validate my node app using google. But I found these two modules being used in different tutorials. Could you please tell what the difference is between these two.

**passport-google-token**

> On the npmjs.com page of both, i found the desc as  Passport strategy
>   for authenticating with Google access tokens using the OAuth 2.0 API.
>   This module lets you authenticate using Google in your Node.js
>   applications. By plugging into Passport, Google authentication can be
>   easily and unobtrusively integrated into any application or framework
>   that supports Connect-style middleware, including Express.

**passport-google-oauth**

> Passport strategies for authenticating with Google using OAuth 2.0.
>
> Lead Maintainer: David Pate
>
> This module lets you authenticate using Google in your Node.js
>   applications. By plugging into Passport, Google authentication can be
>   easily and unobtrusively integrated into any application or framework
>   that supports Connect-style middleware, including Express.

Answer (score 0):

**passport-google-oauth** was made for express apps, so you can configure permissions, callback uri and request user data, all in the same place.

**passport-google-token** is made for REST APIs, so you handle authentication logic in front-end and then, you send google token to the back-end (node server) and there you can request user data using google token and grant access to your app using your own authentication mechanism (JWT, Bearer Token, etc.).