# What purpose does the clientSecret serve in the passport strategy passport-google-token?

Tags: typescript, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, passport.js, nestjs

I am building an API in nest.js, which is consumed by,  amongst other things,  a react application. The react application handles OAuth flow on the frontend and sends an access token to the backend to verify the user.

Nest.js uses a passport wrapper to handle its authentication, and i have deduced as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51983833/what-is-the-difference-between-passport-google-oauth-and-passport-google-token) that the strategy i want is `passport-google-token` since i already have an access token coming from the frontend that is hosted on a separate domain.

The documentation for `passport-google-token` states that you provide a client id and a secret that is used during the decoding stage, however i have learned that that is actually not needed. I can successfully retrieve the profile data from the access token without a correct secret or id, even when the access token has been issued from a different oauth2 project. In addition to that, my research suggests that that is the whole point of the access tokens that you recieve for google.

So my questions are as follows, what, if any, is the purpose of the secret and client id in the library `passport-google-token`? Is there a better alternative solution? Should i just perform the database lookup using the profile information and call it a day? My gut feeling says that it is a security issue, but  on the other hand, i have allready signed the token on the frontend, and ill just reject the auth request if the user cannot be found in the database.

Many thanks in advance for any answers